# Populate an array by splitting a string

Tags: perl

I am trying to convert a string into an array based on space delimiter.

My input file looks like this:

```
>Reference
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnctcACCATGGTGTCGACTC
TTCTATGGAAACAGCGTGGATGGCGTCTCCAGGCGATCTGACGGTTCACTAAACGAGCTC
```

Ignoring the line starting with `>`, the length of rest of the string is 360.

I am trying to convert this into an array.

Here's my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#### To to change bases with less than 10X coverage to N #####

#### Take depth file and consensus fasta file as input arguments ####

my ($in2) = @ARGV;

my $args = $#ARGV + 1;

if ( $args != 1 ) {
    print "Error!!! Insufficient Number of Argumrnts\n";
    print "Usage: $0 <consensus fasta file> \n";
}

#### Open a filehandle to read in consensus fasta file ####

    my $FH2;
    my $line;
    my @consensus;
    my $char;

    open($FH2, '<', $in2) || die "Could not open file $in2\n";

    while ( <$FH2> ) {
        $line = $_;
        chomp $line;
        next if $line =~ />/; # skip header line 
        $line =~ s/\s+//g;

        my $len = length($line);
        print "$len\n";
        #print "$line";

        @consensus = split(// , $line);
        print "$#consensus\n";
        #print "@consensus\n";

        #for $char (0 .. $#consensus){
    #   print "$char: $consensus[$char]\n";
     #   }
    }
```

The problem is the `$len` variable returns a value of 60 instead of 360 and `$#consensus` returns a value of 59 instead of 360 which is the length of the string.

I have removed the whitespace after each line with code `$line =~ s/\s+//g;`but it still is not working.

Comment: You say you want to *"convert a string into an array based on space delimiter"* but the code you have written splits on tabs. Furthermore, I don't see where those spaces/tabs can be in your sample input data. You also do nothing to remove the header line beginning with `>`.

Comment: Hi I have added code to remove the header which is next if $line =~ />/. Also, I will edit my code so you can get a clear idea of what i am trying to do. The input file has 60 characters per line. I tried removing the carriage returns \r, newlines \n to no avail. It still reads a line and and stores it as array index which is not what I want. I want each character of the input line to be stored as elements of an array.

Comment: `my $args = $#ARGV + 1;` is rather an obfuscated way to write `my $args = @ARGV;`.

Comment: @Callie: So you're not in fact *"trying to convert a string into an array based on space delimiter"*? I think you need `push @consensus, split //, $line`. The array will be complete only after the end of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is essentially working. It's just your checking logic that makes no sense. I'd do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if (@ARGV != 1) {
    print STDERR "Usage: $0 <consensus fasta file>\n";
    exit 1;
}

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "$0: cannot open $ARGV[0]: $!\n";

my @consensus;
while (my $line = readline $fh) {
    next if $line =~ /^>/;

    $line =~ s/\s+//g;
    push @consensus, split //, $line;
}

print "N = ", scalar @consensus, "\n";
```

Main things to note:

- Error messages should go to `STDERR`, not `STDOUT`.
- If an error occurs, the program should exit with an error code, not keep running.
- Error messages should include the name of the program and the reason for the error.
- `chomp` is redundant if you're going to remove all whitespace anyway.
- As you're processing the input line by line, you can just keep pushing elements to the end of `@consensus`. At the end of the loop it'll have accumulated all characters across all lines.
- Examining `@consensus` within the loop makes little sense as it hasn't finished building yet. Only after the loop do we have all characters we're interested in.

Comment: `warn` better than `print STDERR` since it's hookable. Also, shorter